# How to combine 2 select statements in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've had a simple SELECT combined with INSERT INTO output table which was working fine, but now I have to select part of the data with different WHERE clause and don't know how to combine it.

The source data table have columns like this:
Date, ID, Sales, Cor1, Cor2, Cor3, Cor4

Then I have "filter" table defining combination of IDs and dates in format:
ID, Start_date, End_date

So original query was like this:

```
INSERT INTO sales_export ( ID, Sales, Cor1, Cor2, Cor3, Cor4 )
SELECT Tsales.ID, Sum(Tsales.Sales) AS Sales, Sum(Tsales.Cor1) AS Cor1, Sum(Tsales.Cor2) AS Cor2, Sum(Tsales.Cor3) AS Cor3, Sum(Tsales.Cor4) AS Cor4
FROM Tsales, Tfilter
WHERE (((Tsales.ID)=Tfilter.ID) And ((Tsales.Date) Between Tfilter.Start_date And Tfilter.End_date))
GROUP BY Tsales.ID
```

But now the conditions have changed and all fields except Cor3 have same dates, so I need separate SELECT for Cor3 and all the rest and then combine it and insert into export table.

Any ideas? I was trying to play with 2 selects using UNION and JOIN, but it wasn't working due to syntax errors which I can't figure out.

Thanks

Comment: Post the query that you tried using `UNION/JOIN`

Comment: `UNION` is the correct approach, so show us the query you tried  and that fails

Comment: UNION is not working as it's saying the number of columns in tables doesn't match which is if I understand correctly UNION function a must. I will try to play with JOIN and post my tries if will not be able to figure it out. Another problem is that the order of the columns have to be same, so I will probably need 3 queries in order to do so.

Comment: At the at I had created 2nd table which I started to fill with the data after the change and then used UNION to put them together. Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join one more Tsales table with ID (if ID is unique)
and your code should look like this one:

```
INSERT INTO sales_export ( ID, Sales, Cor1, Cor2, Cor3, Cor4 )
SELECT T1.ID, Sum(T1.Sales) AS Sales, Sum(T1.Cor1) AS Cor1, Sum(T1.Cor2) AS Cor2, Sum(T2.Cor3) AS Cor3, Sum(T1.Cor4) AS Cor4
FROM ((Tsales T1) JOIN Tfilter T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID) LEFT JOIN Tsales T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID AND T3.Date BETWEEN [Your New Date1] AND [Your New Date2]
WHERE ((T1.Date) Between T2.Start_date And T2.End_date))
GROUP BY T1.ID
```